# Add data into database at particular time

Tags: postgresql, events

I am using PostgreSQL(pgAdmin III) "Function"(eg:- `insert_day(character varying,character varying,character varying))` to insert a date into database.
For that, I have to write the query for each day like:-

---

```
 1. SELECT insert_day('11/02/2019','dd/mm/yyyy','WEEK_DAY');
 2. SELECT insert_day('03/02/2019','dd/mm/yyyy','WEEK_END');
```

And So on...

*Question*:

I want to create an event that will run automatically based on calendar days to insert all the data(365 days data) automatically on a particular day like on 15th of December.

Comment: Look into pgagent, I've used it once or twice long ago to schedule stuff in postgres.

Comment: ..Or run a cron job from the host

Comment: Also take a look at the generate_series() function.